# Отскок мяча от земли

Tags: анимация, алгоритм, javascript, физика

У нас есть холст высотой **my** и шириной **mx**, на котором мы рисуем окружность с центром в точке (**x**;**y**) радиуса **r**, на расстоянии **h** "от земли". (h = my - y).

Начальная скорость падения окружности вниз равна 0. Будем считать, что масса окружности прямо пропорциональна радиусу, то есть масса **m** = **r**.

Каждый кадр мы рассчитываем координаты окружности и затем прорисовываем ее. Допустим, в более сложном случае окружность может падать не строго вниз, а под углом и с какой-то начальной скоростью.

```
var obj = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    radius: radius,
    x_: 0,
    y_: 0,
    speed: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x_, 2) + Math.pow(this.y_, 2)),
    angle: Math.atan2(this.y_, this.x_),
    time: 0,
    h: my - y
};
```

Пусть **x__** и **y__** - скорости (проекции скоростей) на оси Ох и Оу соответственно. Пусть **g** = 9.8. Каждый шаг я буду изменять координаты шарика

```
obj.time += 0.0051;
obj.y_ = (g * Math.pow(obj.time, 2))/2;
obj.speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(obj.x_, 2) + Math.pow(obj.y_, 2)); // * (-1)
obj.angle = Math.atan2(obj.y_, obj.x_);
obj.y -= obj.speed * Math.sin( obj.angle );
```

Ввожу вектор, т.к. возможно в будущем сделаю анимацию более сложной.

**Вопрос:**
Как поступать, когда мяч прилетел на землю? Как перенаправить вектор, чтобы шар отскочил обратно вверх? Как привязать сопротивление воздуха и массу шарика (чтобы большой мяч летел быстрее или медленнее)? Как сделать так, чтобы шар в конце концов остановился? Желательно сделать все как можно ближе к настоящим законам физики.

Куда копать? Пожалуйста, разъясните поподробней этот вопрос.
И что можно почитать на эту тему, чтобы я потом не создавал вопрос о том, как сделать то же самое с какой-то неправильной фигурой (и т.д.)?

Comment: Достойная задача. Вы молодец. Предлагаю для начала реализовать падение строго вниз. Тогда будет меньше сил действовать на мяч, для начала это поможет разработать концепцию воздействия например гравитации. Нужен ещё какой-то условный коэффициент упругости.

Comment: Я бы наоборот предложил сразу для N-мерного пространства писать. Тогда и для одномерного и для 2d и для 3D проблем не будет.
Просто по циклу аккуратно пробегаем по всем проекциям.

Answer (score 9):

Для начала почитайте школьную механику.
Если мяч несжимаемый, при касании мячом земли

```
vy=-vy;
```

Мгновенно.
Если сжимаемый, то при касании появляется сила упругости, которая добавляет ускорение.
В простейшем случае

```
Fупр = -kdy,// где dy - смещение по y.
```

Эта сила сначала уменьшит скорость y до 0, потом возвратит к первоначальной величине с обратным знаком.

Сопротивление воздуха

```
F = Cx((pV^2)*S)/2

Cx - коэффициент лобового сопротивления.  Для шара примерно 0.5
p - плотность среды. Для воздуха - 1.3кг/m^3
S - площадь сечения шара. pi*r*r
V - скорость (ПОЛНАЯ, не только по y!!!), относительно воздуха.
```

Не забудте, что эта сила ВСЕГДА направлена против движения.

Далее. Если пол шершавый, а касание не единомоментно, мячик будет подкручиваться.
Инерция вращающегося шара - что-то типа

```
(2/5)mR^2,
```

то есть в вашем случае

```
(2/5)r^3
```

Вам пока хватит. Точно хватит. =)

P.S. Ах, да. Еще учтите силу архимеда для мячика: p_воздуха*Объем_мяча

Comment: Ну Вот ты его наверное сейчас напугал)

Comment: не больше, чем обычно пугают, когда дают кучу ссылок на теорию. Я почти все формулы привел.

UPD: ...и коэффициенты тоже, кстати!
UPDD: человек просил поближе к реальной физике. ^___^ Еще можно силу кулона при электризации учесть, турбулентности, подъем теплого воздуха, нагреваемого от трения, изменение коэффициента упругости при деформации мяча, потери на внутреннее трение...

Comment: @knes ага, и космическое излучение в разные моменты времени :D

Comment: `vy=-vy` не вполне верно в случае наклонного полёта мяча.

Правильно так: разложить вектор `v` на компоненту, нормальную поверхности, и остаток — параллельную поверхости. Параллельная компонента не меняется, перпендикулярная обращает знак.

Comment: дык vy и есть перпендикулярная компонента. :)
...иначе он будет отскакивать строго назад, как от угла

Comment: @knes: и правда :-)

Answer (score 4):

круто весь мир описать наверное и знать при этом всю физику да ещё и математику, но к счастью, а быть может и нет, достаточно создавать иллюзии тех или иных проявлений посредством программинга ибо это и есть симулятор(тобиш иллюзия). и если нет готового движка(которых уже достаточно) ябы это решил функцией падения с эффектом рикошета. тоесть пишем функцию допустим

func(int x, int y, int x_destination, int y_destination, int speed)

как-то так..

и алгоритм примерно такой:

при столкновении с землей вектор на

+-180градусов, если движение на 90градусов(перпендикулярно земле)

+90градусов, если точка отсчета(старта) больше точки достижения земли по оси Х и У

-90градусов, если точка отсчета(старта) меньше точки достижения земли по оси Х и больше по оси У

уменьшаем скорость и меняем x_destination, y_destination допустим на отрезок 1/5 от начального при достижении новой точки назначения на +-180градусов и опять к земле и так пока скорость превышает допустим 1
конечно это только набросок и на идеал никоим образом не претендует, только чтобы подсказать направление

Answer (score 0):

Когда то простую симуляцию отскока мяча (тогда не нужна была оптимизация ) я реализовывал рекурсивно. Каждый отскок будто новый бросок под уголом к горизонту с соответствующим изменением скорости и угла. Базовым случаем являлось условие равенства скорости нулю.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]